# SAP Webservice Client - Deserialization failed

Tags: c#, deserialization, webservice-client, sap-basis, soapexception

I've created a simple Net WebSvc Client which receives an up to date reference of a SAP WebSvc. It expects a String, and four elements sent by reference: three arrays of custom objects and another custom object outside any collection structure (which I have their format in the reference page)

When the request to perform the operation is called, I get this exception on the call row. (*At the bottom I write: An extract of my code, the Reference.cs method I call, and the error, as complete as I can.*)

> SoapException "Deserialization failed"

Investigating through the net, I've found [this](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1140491) Thread of a SAP forum where someone answers that the common problems that show this error are, *unupdated wsdl* and *underscore in the member variable names* but neither of them are my case. In fact the thread continued but without any response to the guy with the same issue as me.

Anyways, I guess Stack Overflow guys are more active than that ;-)

Thanks in advance people!

---

**Extract of my code:**

```
 string destiny = "myDest";
 ZICQService ZICQ = new ZICQService();
 ZtyEE070[] innerHeadList = HeadLst.ToArray();
 ZtyEE071[] innerObjList = ObjLst.ToArray();
 Zrequest[] innerTRequest = TRequest.ToArray();
 //This is the row of the Deserialization failed
 Bapiret2 respnse = svc.ZbcInsertRequest(destiny, ref innerHeadList, ref innerObjList, IClrQst, ref innerTRequest);
```

And this is my web service **Reference.cs attached method:**

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute
    ("", RequestNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style", 
    ResponseNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style", 
    Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Return", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public Bapiret2 ZbcInsertRequest(
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute
        (Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    string Destino, 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute
        (Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute
        ("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)] 
    ref ZtyEE070[] EtRequestHeader, 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute
        (Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute
        ("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)] 
    ref ZtyEE071[] EtRequestObj, 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute
        (Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    Zclrqstdat IClrqst, 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute
        (Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute
        ("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)] 
    ref Zrequest[] TRequest) 
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("ZbcInsertRequest", new object[] {
                Destino,
                EtRequestHeader,
                EtRequestObj,
                IClrqst,
                TRequest});
    EtRequestHeader = ((ZtyEE070[])(results[1]));
    EtRequestObj = ((ZtyEE071[])(results[2]));
    TRequest = ((Zrequest[])(results[3]));
    return ((Bapiret2)(results[0]));
}
```

**The error:**

> ```
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled  
> Message="Deserialisation failed"  
> Source="System.Web.Services"  
> Actor=""   Lang="en"   Node=""  
> Role=""   StackTrace:
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>    at SCM.Manager.mx.com.hylsamex.hmxwasd1.ZICQService.ZbcInsertRequest(String Destino, ZtyEE070[]& EtRequestHeader, ZtyEE071[]& EtRequestObj, Zclrqstdat IClrqst, Zrequest[]& TRequest) in D:\Documents and Settings\apacay\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Desarrollo SCM\scm.manager\SCM.Manager\Web References\mx.com.hylsamex.hmxwasd1\Reference.cs:line 85
>    at SCM.Manager.SAPDataMockUp.SendOTs() in D:\Documents and Settings\apacay\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Desarrollo SCM\scm.manager\SCM.Manager\SAPDataMockUp.cs:line 164
>    at SCM.Manager.Threads.HandleSap.Send() in D:\Documents and Settings\apacay\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Desarrollo SCM\scm.manager\SCM.Manager\Threads\HandleSap.cs:line 24
>    at SCM.Manager.Front.Main(String[] args) in D:\Documents and Settings\apacay\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Desarrollo SCM\scm.manager\SCM.Manager\Front.cs:line 170
>    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> ```

Comment: anybody found solution ?

Comment: Since I had no answer I went another way, I don't clearly remember how was this solved, but I can tell you it was something inherently of the work SAP had to do.
If I recall correclty, it's a SAP way of explaining you are sending something in a way the wsvc of SAP does not understand some variable of the ones you 've sent.
We are using netweaver now. And this issue went away with the technology change.